# Python: why does the following xpath returns empty list?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to extract some text and links from `instapaper.com`. So I am using the following code to get the job done:

```
>>> import lxml.html as lh
>>> doc = lh.parse("http://www.instapaper.com/u/folder/1227370/programming")
>>> text = doc.xpath(".//*[@id='bookmark_list']/*/div[3]/a/text()")
>>> len(text)
0
>>> text
[]
```

As you can see it returns an empty list which means that it is not able to find any text matching the above xpath .

Now when I use the above `xpath expr` in firebug/firepath it works fine.

[image]

You can see in the above image it shows `40 matching nodes`.

So, my question is why the above xpath expression is not working with python/lxml.

As requested [Instapaper page source](http://pastebin.com/1WpFAfCt)

Comment: Try removing the first period character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no element with the ID `bookmark_list`. Maybe you must be logged in.

**Edit**

Parsing the *real* HTML it works:

```
doc = lh.parse("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1WpFAfCt")
text = doc.xpath("//*[@id='bookmark_list']/*/div[3]/a/text()")
len(text) # => 40
```

Comment: Nice catch. Yes, I am logged in.